# Transformation for parented objects

Tags: coordinates

I need the actual definitions for the transforms of parented objects.

1. It seems that the transform shown when pressing <kbd>N</kbd> shows the local
   transform, and not the global one for child object? That would at least conform with that BGE seems to define as a localPosition and localOrientation
2. Can the <kbd>N</kbd> view be changed to show the world transform in that case?
3. The definition of the local transform for multiple objects being parented seems peculiar.  Especially for multiple objects being parented, and then moved around. Is there a clear definition of this to be found somewhere?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, motion tracking or baking that object's motion would give you global coordinates at any frame.  Do it on a copy of your project file, NOT the original.

Comment: For now I circumvent the problems by only considering global transforms, and then solve for local transforms analytically. Seems like the only foolproof solution so far.